# How do you get a website to adjust to window size?

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS so this may be an elementary question but, when I change my window size, the website does not adjust to the window. Is this a CSS issue or a HTML issue and how do I fix it? Included my HTML just in case. I hope this a bit better, I've added some of my CSS as well. I've included as much as I could, if I try to add more to this post, it gives me an error.

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(#bbab9b, #D9D9D9);
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 319px;
  height: 44px;
  left: 892px;
  top: 284px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 1300;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 48px;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;
  color: black;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 424px;
  height: 175px;
  left: 896px;
  top: 344px;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 34px;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;
  color: black;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Dialya's Portfolio</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <a href="#" class="nav-branding">dialya</a>
      <ul class="nav-menu">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="help.html" class="nav-link"> Home</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="AboutMe.html" class="nav-link"> About Me</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="Projects.html" class="nav-link"> My Projects</a> <br>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="hamburger">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <h1> Hi, I'm Dialya!</h1> <br>
  <h2> I am a multidiciplinary designer based in Memphis, Tennessee. I love to design, code, and research! </h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your CSS also?

Comment: Ofc! Its kinda long though lol.

Comment: you might be interested in this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries

Comment: For the provided HTML, very long CSS would be pretty unexpected.

Comment: look up css media queries

Answer (score 0):

Responsive Web Design. A couple of keys to achieving responsive web design are media queries and [CSS grid layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout) with `fr` units.

> #### [Using media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)
>
> Media queries allow you to apply CSS styles depending on a device's
> general type (such as print vs. screen) or other characteristics such
> as screen resolution or browser viewport width.

> #### Fixed and flexible track sizes
>
> You can create a grid with fixed track sizes – using pixels for example. This sets the grid to the
> specified pixel which fits to the layout you desire. You can also
> create a grid using flexible sizes with percentages or with the **fr**
> unit designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**[Responsive web design](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)** is the real way to solve this. For a simple way, h1 and h2 elements, left and top values change px to % in css.

*NB: The px value is permanent and does not change when resized. But the % value is dynamic, its changed we resize the window*